# SilverStripe routing not working

Tags: php, silverstripe

I created some controllers and routes in SilverStripe but I am unable to access the routes.

http://localhost/silverstripe/teams or http://localhost/silverstripe/player does not work.

**TeamController.php**

```
class TeamController extends Controller {

    private static $allowed_actions = array(
        'players',
        'index'
    );

    public function index(SS_HTTPRequest $request) {
        // ..
    }

    public function players(SS_HTTPRequest $request) {
        print_r($request->allParams());
    }
}
```

**config.yml**

```
---
Name: mysite
After:
- 'framework/*'
- 'cms/*'
---
# YAML configuration for SilverStripe
# See http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/configuration
# Caution: Indentation through two spaces, not tabs
SSViewer:
  theme: 'simple'

Director:
  rules:
    'teams//$Action/$ID/$Name': 'TeamController'
    'player/': 'PlayerController'
    '': 'HomeController'
```

Why are the routes not working?

Comment: You need to indent your yml config correctly… or is that just a copy-paste error? Did you run `dev/build` after updating the config file?

Comment: all indentions ok, and run dev/buil already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transfer this to a `routes.yml`

```
Director:
  rules:
    'teams//$Action/$ID/$Name': 'TeamController'
    'player/': 'PlayerController'
    '': 'HomeController'
```